# Assumed unchanged file changed on pull

Tags: git

I have a file `config.properties` that contains information needed for comunication with a webservice (ie API token etc.) and I don't want this information to become public.

I made the properties empty and the file looked like this:

```
AccessToken=
Domain=
```

then I issued `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.properties` and committed the file.

After that I filled the properties with the information that I needed so the file looked a bit like this:

```
AccessToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Domain=http"//xxx.xxx.xx/xx
```

When I ran `git status` after that the file didn't list as changed, so far so good.

Did the same with the other users contributing to the project and worked fine.

But here's the problem: when I pull the file gets 'reset' to it's 'original' state (ie the 'empty' file) and I end up with this again:

```
AccessToken=
Domain=
```

What have I done wrong? Or is my idea of what `git update-index --assume-unchanged` does wrong?

Comment: Why are you checking in configuration with version control in the first place?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha why not? If it's needed for the application to run?

Comment: Because configuration changes per deploy. I'll have different configuration for production, staging, testing, local and any other environment I may run the code in. Configuration is needed for the application to run, but it is not part of the package.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha never thought about it like that, nevertheless I still face the problem.

Comment: FWIW, you seem to be doing everything right; your file should not be overwritten. If someone else modified the file, you would get an error on pull saying that your local changes would be overwritten.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch that's the weird thing, I have 3 co-contributers to the repository and in all their repo's the fille is assumed unchanged